# htaccess wildcard subdomain redirect with https non www

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, subdomain, wildcard

I have searched and search to no avail. If there is already an answer out there, please let me know.

But I am trying to redirect wildcard subdomains to a specific file with a GET request. At the same time need to redirect to https and non WWW

For Example:
`http://user1.example.com -> https://example.com/index.php?user=user1`
`https://user2.example.com -> http://example.com/index.php?user=user2`

Any help will be forever grateful and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://example.com/index.php?user=%1 [R=302,END]
```

I am slightly unsure that request scheme will work in lower version of apache let me know the result.